# Copy formatted text to clipboard

Tags: copy, clipboard, zeroclipboard, formatted-text

A simple html page has FORMATTED text - not fancy - line breaks, and italic.

I want to have a button that takes this formatted text, and copies it to the clipboard, formatted (it is planned to be pasted into some LibreOffice document later).

Couldn't find how to do it.

I tried ZeroClipboard, and a suggestion to parse the text, replacing "
"-s to "\r\n". That indeed does the trick for line breaks, but what about italic?... Any means to get this functionality?...

Answer (score 0):

When you create an italic tag the responsible for formatting the document and showing the text properly is the browser. If you want to copy the text you should get the text already parse and render by the browser or parse yourself the text like you did with break lines. For italics when you find a  *...*  tag you must create the adequate text. That is, text in italics, but that depends on the language you are using, but i'm sure it can be done.

Comment: This is exactly my question. As said, I will not be copying it from the browser, as it is a human action. I would like to have a button that performs this operation; the question is - how?... As said, I found that LibreOffice line breaks are "\r\n". And so, I replace all "<br>"-s to "\r\n". Now the question is what would be LibreOffice escapings for Italic (to replace "<i>" and "</i>".

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Turns out that ZeroClipboard **had** this functionality (of rendering the HTML text upon paste), but have **disabled** it.

However, the version that supports it can be found at: https://github.com/botcheddevil/ZeroClipboard

*Note:*
You may find that in this version, creating the client, binding the flash to a component, and handling the events are rather different than the documentation of current version of ZeroClipboard (https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md